# How to open cross domain new tab without cache

Tags: javascript

How to open a new tab or navigate to new URL(**cross domain pages**) using javascript. Below makes me navigate but as if browser holds the cache and it sends 'If-Modified-Since' in the header then the server is responding with **304** status. Can we opt to clear cache browser and open a new tab?

Tried below options:

```
url = url+'&d='+new Date().getTime();

 - window.location.href = url;
 - window.location.reload(true);
 - window.location.replace(url);
 - window.open(url,'childwindow');
```

I don't have access to the child page. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Why would you want to clear the cache, if the server indicates that nothing has changed by responding with a 304 …?

Comment: It should go through proxy for every request to hack the response content.

Comment: If it has gone through the proxy for the first request already, then the browser should already have the version with your modifications stored in its cache. Do you need to insert something _different_ every time? If you proxy these requests anyway - can’t you configure the proxy to filter out the If-Modified-Since header the client sends?

Comment: yes, we are passing URL parameters different for second request and browser is not treating it as a new request and loading cache content which is not even reaching our proxied server.

Comment: Then your browser is broken. Different GET parameters mean it is a different URL, the browser *can’t*  fetch that from cache if it did not already request that exact same URL previously ... (Unless there’s actually more going on here than you have told us about so far - f.e. if the remote server _redirects_ both those requests to one and the same URL, then the browser might take the latter from its cache again.)

Comment: do we have any option to remove **If-Modified-Since** header from javascript before I do open a new tab/redirect/navigate?

Comment: No, neither assigning a URL to location.href nor using window.open allows you to interfere which what headers are send in any way. The only way that would be possible, would be with an AJAX or fetch request.

Comment: Not sure how my child page(third party) is doing it but a browser is not able to identify the change in URL parameters as a fresh request.BTW, Thank you for your valuable time.